# Language Switcher Rather Than Separate SO Sites

Tags: discussion, feature-request, language-versions

not sure if this is applicable here (as in on meta site), but is it not more useful to have one SO site with a language selector that allows a more universal way to search/ask/answer?

It will take a while to compile sure, but some people's English isn't great (I'm a native speaker and still suck at it) and SO isn't available in their language, it would bridge a huge gap.

Thanks,

Comment: Not sure I understand your FR fully, but imo having a language switcher implies having the same content on all sites, available in different languages, which clearly is not the case. For me personally this'd just make things unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: @Seth it would mean same content for all sites, it just translates :) and confusing how? (just so I get why :))

Comment: I think the current setup is better than a language selector. If I wasn't a native English writer then I would definitely be more comfortable writing in my native language and therefore, I'd prefer getting answers by people who can express themselves in the same language rather than a translation / language selector service.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs down-votes on meta don't mean the same thing as they do on the main site (they don't minus your rep) and they are commonly used to show disagreements.

Comment: I disagree with an UI that translates since we already get enough non-English content and that'll likely only increase if the UI is non-English too. If there's a large enough demand, people can try and get their language-specific SO via [area51.se]

Comment: @Script47 ah I suppose that's a valid point! How do we then help people who don't have a SO in their native language with little skills in any of the SO's available? And ahhh ok so it's not necessarily a bad question as such (even if it may be in this case)? :)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Area 51 exists for a reason, if there is enough support for a particular language then a site can be established for it. For those small numbers of people who require help can write their questions, comments and or answers in to Google Translate or some other translation service. It may not seem ideal but remember, creating a feature as you are suggesting requires resources and that requires money.

Comment: @Script47 OK will do that for the small cases :) ty :)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth ok ty :)

Comment: Remember, as long as you can get your point across and your question is decent, people won't penalise you for mistakes in your English. Heck, if they see that you made a real attempt they'll even edit your question to help you.

Comment: If you think *automatic machine translation* will solve the problem, you have way too much faith in automatic machine translation. It simply does not work *that* well.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth As of current writing, [SE is not accepting proposal for new language-specific SO at the moment](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20987/internationalization-state-of-the-stack-stack-overflow-edition)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're proposing to localise the UI *and/or* user contributed content by way of machine translation, then you have way too much faith in machine translation. It simply doesn't work all that well, certainly not well enough to build a community on.

There would be only two approaches here:

- Everyone tags their posts with what language it's written in, and a "language selector" would filter out content and only show you content in that language.

  1. People would mistag posts a lot.
  2. It's one more step/variable to keep track of when posting something.
  3. This is essentially how the system already works, only that things are segregated into entirely different sites instead of filtering within one site.
  4. I can see an advantage to this if the same Q&A could be hand-translated into other languages, to unify problems and their solutions into one resource, like Wikipedia sites. The big BUT here is: who's gonna do all that work? It simply doesn't scale the way the site currently works.
- Anything goes, everyone writes in whatever language they want. Automatic translation translates it into your local language.

  1. Again, automatic translation simply isn't that good. There's a reason [Google Translate et al. get made fun of](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLGnYtw5ezZI-BnVCUhMOcBqi9KggS1fhD).
  2. So discounting automatic translation as an option, you'd have a wild mixup of languages. It's already hard enough to find content you're interested in/can comprehend, erecting language barriers on top makes this even worse.

So, mmm, yeah, nah. Hard pass.